# UIPrintErrorDomain error 4 while printing on the same printer

Tags: swift, xcode, ios13, airprint

I have an application that uses AirPrint and currently, after the first printing I get the following error:
UIPrintErrorDomain error 4

I keep the UIPrinter in a variable that will be used on the next prints(as Apple advice) and when I do a `contactPrinter`, it actually says that it's available. Even that, it doesn't work.

The only solution is to bring back again the UIPrinterPickerController, choose the printer and then, it will work.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: We are experiencing the same -- in iOS 13, not in older versions -- and have not found a reference to a fix. Have you figured anything out?

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue here, as well.  I've ripped my app apart as I was saving the UIPrinter to a singleton object for re-use, and re-built to hold a strong reference to the UIPrinter.  Even this, however, causes the same symptoms you're referencing (only prints once, then I have to choose the printer again).  This only began after iOS 13 came along, though I can now replicate it on devices running 12.4.x, as well.

Comment: So far I haven't been able of finding a proper solution. One thing that worked was recreating the UIPrinter on every print, that solves it for most of the Airprinters I've tested but I still experience it in a few. For now, we have included the standarrd selector of iOS to let the user choose the printer..

Comment: If it is still actual - left my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59668291/10521225)